# Is there a way to use regex expression in vscode snippet prefix?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I read the document and it seems that regex expression is only used in snippet body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex's can only be used to transform snippet variables in the body of the snippet, but you can put multiple snippet prefixes like this:

```
"stripLastDirectory": {
  "prefix": ["lsd", "lsf", "lsq"],
   "body": [
      "${TM_DIRECTORY/.*[\\\\|\\/]+(.*)/$1/}"
  ],
},
```

So perhaps you can accomplish what you need that way.

---

Another alternative with some pluses (can use javascript within the snippet!) and minuses (no support for vscode variables like `${file}`) is the extension [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) which does allow you to use pure regex for snippet "prefixes".