# Multiple snippet prefixes in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write a snippet that allows me to `console.log()`.
The following only works when I type `con`.

```
"Print to console": {
    "prefix": "con",
    "body": [
        "console.log($1);"
    ]
}
```

I want it to work for all the following letters as well (e.g. `cons`, `conso`, `consol`, `console`).
Is it possible or I have to duplicate the snippet as many times?
Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [Is there a way to use regex expression in vscode snippet prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388765/is-there-a-way-to-use-regex-expression-in-vscode-snippet-prefix/54390612#54390612) but not really a duplicate as that question asked about using regexs (which would be pretty interesting) to construct snippet prefixes.

You can put it into one snippet ala:

```
"Print to console": {
    "prefix": ["con", "cons", "conso", ….etc...],
    "body": [
        "console.log($1);"
    ]
}
```